# Golang: No response from get.http( url )

Tags: xml, http, url, go

```
http://plg1.yumenetworks.com/dynamic_preroll_playlist.vast2xml?domain=2210cZDclAme
```

when I call the link above from the server using `http.Get` I get this response, an empty XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VAST version="2.0">

</VAST>
```

But when I call it from the browser it responsed with a valid XML,also when I called the link from a local server it works.

```
func getXmlVast(url string) (string, error) {

        resp, err := http.Get(url)
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        // read xml http response
        xmlData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
        return string(xmlData), nil
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's response with empty xml for me from browser. Maybe you got result from your browser because you are logged-in or you got something in your coockies. Try open 'Private tab' from your browser and check your URL there

Comment: it works, I tried from a local server and it works also

Comment: I get an empty XML from my browser as well, so I guess problem lies outside of Go. You need to figure out what makes your browser and "a local server" so special to receive the expected content.

Comment: Hmm, then I think it has a relation with **geolocation** because im in Spain and the server is in France  and you're from UK ^^. from Spain it works and from the other location no.

Comment: Don't test with a browser, which can add other factors that change behavior. I get a full response with curl and Go. You're not checking the response code or the headers, there might be more information there when the response isn't correct.

Comment: @JimB I didn't get what do you mean

Comment: @Aziz: What didn't you get? Check the response code, and headers to see if the server is returning any more information.

Comment: @JimB it doesn't work, I think as I said it's a **geolocation** probleme  I will ask the provider to be sure, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get an empty response because you haven't specified the response headers type. Try to add:

```
resp, err := http.Get(url)
resp.Header.Add("Accept", "application/xml")
resp.Header.Add("Content-Type","application/xml; charset=utf-8")

if err != nil {
     return "", err
}
```

Maybe this will solve your problem.